# I am trying to read an JPEG image, which is of 32 bits pixels, but ImageIO.read(new File(path)).getColorModel() akways returns 24 bits

Tags: jpeg, bufferedimage, 32-bit, javax.imageio, twelvemonkeys

I am trying to read an JPEG image, which is of 32 bits pixels, but ImageIO.read(new File(path)).getColorModel() akways returns 24 bits and image get inverted or doesnt appear properly.

Also Sanselan.getBufferedImage(imageFIle) throws the exceptions for Jpeg image stating the jpegs images are not supported.

Please advise how to render the image which of 32 bits pixels

Read the image of 32bits pixels and use it in the pdf document

Comment: What do you mean by JPEG "of 32 bits pixels"? Do you mean a 4 channel JPEG with 8 bits/channel? Do you mean CMYK, RGBA or other color model? Can you share the JPEG file? Perhaps also the code you have tried that didn't work (with proper formatting)...